# Открыть пару псевдо-терминалов

Tags: linux, консоль, terminal

Как в linux pty\pts открыть пару и не писать для этого код. Просто подключить cat на одну сторону, на вторую сторону прицепить мою программку.

Программа должна работать с ком портом, но пока хочу подсунуть ей псевдо-терминал, чтоб ручками кидать тестовые данные.

Пробовал socat, но там не понятно как получить доступ к pts снаружи и какой именно терминал был выделен. В мане есть pty, но применения у него там немного не те.

Pipe и fifo мне не подходят. Pipe из-за того что O_NOCTTY, а fifo одностороннее.

Более подробный рецепт для socat может кто подскажет.

Суть того что я хочу: в одном терминале запускаю `cat <> /dev/master-pseudotty-device` или `picocom /dev/master-pseudotty-device`, в втором `./moya_proga /dev/slave-pseudotty-device`.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен: `cat | prog`, а при чём здесь терминалы?  "Как в linux pty\pts и не писать для этого код" - а что в linux?

Comment: Если программа без аргументов, то `script -c ./your-prog` делает это

Comment: *man socat* поможет. Более того его можно потом оставить для работы и с последовательными портами, и удалёнными соединениями.

Comment: @0xdb, пайп не пойдёт. отдельный терминал хочу

Comment: @0andriy сокатом пробовал, но ман мне не очень помог. Сокат открывает птс, но не знаю как у него понять какая из птс его

Comment: @avp script тоже не то.

Comment: расписал поподробнее задачку на свежую голову

Comment: чем это отличается от запуска программы в терминале? Нужно имя текущего терминала узнать? Что происходит `./your-program /dev/tty`?

Comment: `./your-program /dev/tty` - вся обработка вываливается только когда я нажму `ctrl+d`

Comment: И все же, чем `script -с` не подходит? Я посмотрел повнимательней, если нужно передать в программу аргументы, то можно передавать в кавычках. Вот так, например, `script -c "od -bc /dev/tty"`  od будет читать из псевдотерминала, то что вы печатаете

Comment: @avp /dev/tty не подходит - блокируется stdin\stdout
мне не ввод-вывод, а отдельный терминал бы

Comment: Кажется понял. Вы хотите, чтобы ваша программа сохранила stdin/stdout связанные с /dev/tty окна, в котором запущена и получила доступ к pty (его имя передается вам как параметр) с которым работает, скажем, cat, запущенный из другого окна.  Так?

Comment: @avp да, /dev/tty не трогаем

Comment: @eri, мне кажется проще написать (используя openpty и напечатав полученное имя слейва) самому, чем найти в этой помойке, которая называется интернет

Comment: Да ну? Плохо читали документацию. socat — именно то, что нужно.

Comment: @0andriy , плохо читал, 3 раза полностью, но всеравно не уловлю как из него слейв вынуть...

Comment: eri, @Fat-Zer нашел ответ на мой вопрос [Как добавить /dev/pty в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759516/232). Если еще интересно, то там в комментариях. Суть в том, что к опциям запуска ядра (например, отредактировав файл /etc/default/grub) надо добавить `pty.legacy_count=<n>`

Answer (score 1):

За полчаса гугления ничего готового не нашел (наверное искать не умею).

Попробуйте

```
// compile with -lutil
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pty.h>


int
main (int ac, char* av[])
{
  char ptys_name[256]; 
  fd_set rfd;

  struct termios tt;
  int master, slave;
  int n, nfds, cc;

  if (tcgetattr (0, &tt) < 0) 
    exit((perror("Can't get stdin tcgetattr"), 1));
  cfmakeraw (&tt);
  if (openpty (&master, &slave, ptys_name, &tt, 0) < 0)
    exit((perror("Can't open pty"), 1));
  puts(ptys_name);
  //   tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tt);  // tty (stdin) RAW-mode (not debugged)


  nfds = master + 1;
  for (;;) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    FD_ZERO(&rfd);  
    FD_SET(master, &rfd);
    FD_SET(0, &rfd);
    if ((n = select(nfds, &rfd, 0, 0, NULL)) < 0)
      if (errno == EINTR)
        continue;
      else
        exit((perror("select"), 1));

    if (n > 0) {
      if (FD_ISSET(master, &rfd)) 
        if ((cc = read(master, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
          (void) write(1, buf, cc); // echo to stdout

      if (FD_ISSET(0, &rfd))
        if ((cc = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
          if (write(master, buf, cc) < 0)
            fputs("Can't write to slave\n", stderr);
    }
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Имя slave, которое напечатает  программа, передаете параметром в свою. Там открываете на read-write (или в разных файлах, как удобнее) и используете как терминал.

Эта прога копирует stdin из окна в slave, эти символы вы читаете. А то, что пишете в этот slave она печатает в окошке.

Работу в RAW режиме не отлаживал (как-нибудь уж сами посмотрите)

Comment: спасибо за пример

Comment: @eri, я попробовал сделать именно то, что вам нужно, т.е. пару pty/tty в bsd-style (а не ptmx/pts как в ответе), но в моей убунте не заработало (если интересно, я задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759516/232))

Comment: @eri, в рамках того, что доступно (ptmx/pts) похоже можно сделать такую штуку. В программе в ответе делаем 2 пары мастер-слейв, печатаем имена слейвов, а в цикле делаем proxy. Т.е. то, что читаем с одного мастера пишем во второй, а с второго в первый. Тогда ваша программа получает в аргументе имя, например, `slave1` и работает с ним как с терминалом (ее stdin-stdout остаются связанными с окошком). В паре других окошек запускаем `cat slave2` (он будет печатать вывод вашей программы в `slave1`) и `cat >slave2` (тут вы набиваете ввод, который попадет в `slave1` в вашей проге).

Comment: Если такая симуляция вам подойдет, то могу написать (правда, срочность не обещаю...)

Comment: Балуюсь с libuv пока..)

Comment: OK. Хотите с ней сервис pty сделать?

Comment: да, там асинхронная читалка