# Как добавить /dev/pty в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Не получается открывать псевдотерминалы в BSD стиле.

Система:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

После загрузки в `/dev/` не было файлов **pty..** и соответствующих им tty...

Создание их

```
cd /dev; MAKEDEV pty; MAKEDEV tty
```

руками не помогло. Т.е. файлы в /dev теперь есть (с правами все вроде бы нормально), но программа их не открывает (`cat: /dev/ptya0: No such device or address`).

Добавление создания pty в `/etc/rc.local` (т.е. попробовал (зачем?) делать при загрузке) тоже не помогло.

***Вопрос -- как сделать в Ubuntu работающие /dev/pty...?***

P.S.
Я подозреваю, что ядро собирается без нужных модулей, т.е. при сборке нет CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS, 
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY_COUNT

**Update**
Оказывается система все же  собрана с BSD style `CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS = y`, но `CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY_COUNT = 0` (смотрел в `/boot/config-4.4.0-104-generic`).

***Кто знает*** (не получается найти в сети), ***как динамически*** (пересобирать ее мне все равно не из чего), т.е. меняя какой-то из файлов в `/proc/sys` (или другим способом?), ***изменить этот параметр?***
В выводе `sysctl -a` этого параметра похоже нет (кстати, а как он должен в выводе `sysctl` называться?), из относящихся к *pty* там только *kernel.pty.max = 4096*,
 *kernel.pty.nr = 11* (ну, это текущее количество открытых pts) и 
*kernel.pty.reserve = 1024*. Насколько я понимаю это параметры UNIX98 pseudoterminals

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а чего ему не работать через /dev/ptmx -- /dev/pts/... ?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/pty.7.html

Comment: @StackOverflow, в самом деле думаете, что я все это не читал? Вопрос же, что делать, если созданный /dev/ptyp1 (к примеру) не открывается? Видимо как-то надо добавить драйвер (для его major) к ядру. Причем, сам я ядро не собираю, это LTS, поэтому интересна инструкция, когда после автообновлений все опять не ломается.

Comment: /proc/config.gz есть? в убунтах обычно есть. посмотри там флаги

Comment: а /dev/ptmx может всетаки использовать? Since  kernel  2.6.4,  BSD-style
       pseudoterminals  are  considered  deprecated (they can be disabled when
       configuring the kernel); UNIX 98 pseudoterminals should be used in  new
       applications.

Comment: @eri, в самом деле в /boot/config-4.4.0-104-generic (у меня похоже конфиг там) CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS=y (значит драйвер в сборку включен?)
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY_COUNT=0. Интересно, как этот COUNT поменять где-нибудь в /sys, чтобы LEGACY_PTYS заработали

Comment: @eri, /dev/ptmx использовать можно, только proxy с чтением-записью мастеров надо делать для пары pty (слейвы отдаем аппликайшенам). Мне самому стало интересно, получится ли  с LEGACY pty/tty обмен между программами без всяких прокси (только создатель псевдотерминала, но он не должен ничего в процессе обмена делать)

Comment: что-то не нахожу

Comment: Через sys или proc поменять в принципе не возможно... но можно во время загрузки передать ядру `pty.legacy_count=<n>`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо. На  днях попробую

Comment: @Fat-Zer, попробовал, добавлял в /etc/default/grub, получил после перзагрузки в /proc/cmdline `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic root=UUID=a0373d84-7984-4f4a-abbf-190b26f83255 ro quiet pty.legacy_count=64 splash`, но пока ничего не изменилось. cat /dev/ttya1 говорит no such address. Попробую завтра-послезавтра программно с pty поработать, как положено, но чую не пройдет...

Comment: @avp, первый подчинённый терминал `/dev/ttyp0`. `/dev/ttya1` — 177-й, а их создано только 64, понятно, что его нет. Устройства `/dev/{pty,tty}` появились?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ага (ну, устройства у меня были (только не функционировали), я их в /etc/rc.local MAKEDEV-ом делал). Теперь заработали. Надо было не жмотничать а сразу pty.legacy_count=256. Спасибо. А оформите, как ответ, может кто-то набредет через гугл? (комментарии-то не индексируются)

Comment: @avp лучше самостоятельно... мне, честно сказать, не особо хочется формулировать и вылизывать это до полноценного ответа...